# No output when using awk inside bash script

Tags: bash, awk

My bash script is:

```
output=$(curl -s http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-south-africa-2012/engine/current/match/534225.html | sed -nr 's/.*<title>(.*?)<\/title>.*/\1/p')

score=echo"$output" | awk '{print $1}'
echo $score
```

The above script prints just a `newline` in my console whereas my required output is

```
$ curl -s http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-south-africa-2012/engine/current/match/534225.html | sed -nr 's/.*<title>(.*
?)<\/title>.*/\1/p' | awk '{print $1}'

SA
```

So, why am I not getting the output from my bash script whereas it works fine in terminal am I using `echo"$output"` in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(curl -s http://www.espncricinfo.com/england-v-south-africa-2012/engine/current/match/534225.html | sed -nr 's/.*<title>(.*?)<\/title>.*/\1/p')
score=$( echo "$output" | awk '{ print $1 }' )

echo "$score"
```

Score variable was probably empty, since your syntax was wrong.

Comment: The syntax is not universally wrong, it just sets `$score` to `echo$output` and pipes the output of assignment (which is none) to `awk` ;-)